# MasterPages and relative url issue

Tags: asp.net, url, navigation, master-pages

I have a masterpage on which I have included a search bar. i retrieve the record with the ajax method. the problem now is that when I navigate accross the pages the context of the relative path changes. because some pages are in different folders. I have used this url

```
   url: "WebServiceSearchUsers.asmx/SearchUser",
```

but this is not suitable method. Now how to write this code to fix the relative path issue. I don't want to use absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that line of code is in your masterpage (rather than in a separate js file) then you can do this:

```
url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/WebServiceSearchUsers.asmx/SearchUser") %>',
```

Comment: If your code is in a js file, then I would create a global variable that contains the root url of your site, that you can then use to build your absolutes urls dynamically.